# Input textfield autocomplete has too much space on mobile devices

Tags: css

when i enter some text in inputTextfield, autocomplete list coming with some extra space in mobile version of site in css.

Here is a screenshot:
[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Can you share your code ?

Comment: Can you post your code please? Since you're new to Stack Overflow, have a read of the guide on how to ask a good question here https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: <form id="formdata" class="col-xs-12 col-sm-8 col-sm-offset-2">
      <div style="display: none" class="alert alert-success" id="alert-success"></div>
      <div style="display: none" class="alert alert-danger" id="alert-danger"></div>

Comment: can you provide a link to your website at least?

Comment: @sTx https://gorditachallenge.com/ this my web site link

Comment: looks like a problem with the modal itself, if I do `width:100%` on `.modal.in .modal-dialog` problem is resolved but the modal still is out of boundaries of phone screen. PS I use chrome simulator of iphone 5

Comment: also I see that `.modal:before` has a height of `100%` which makes the modal appear at the bottom of the page so you need to scroll down to reach it

Comment: ok, after more close look the problem come from `div#recaptcha` which contains that `iframe` with so many fixed width elements inside of it